# Video array not defined when i try to loop through them

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I am trying to run a slideshow of videos that continuously loops. I have set the array based on div id but I am getting an error message stating that the index is not defined. Here is the html:

```
<div id="div1" class="video"><video class="vidarray" src="icx.mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div2" class="video"><video class="vidarray" src="icx2.mp4"></video></div>
<div id="div3" class="video"><video class="vidarray" src="lastvid.mp4"></video></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
height: 1080px;
width: 1920px;
display: none;
}
```

jquery :

```
var videos = [
'div1',
'div2',
'div3',
 ]
var videos = [
['div1' , 2000],
['div2' , 2000],
['div3' , 2000],
]

// Initate a counter at 1 because you're going to show the first video by default.
var counter = 1;
setInterval(function(){
// Hide all the video divs
$(".video").hide();
// Show the video div based on the counter
$('#'+ videos[counter][0]).show();
 // Reset the video to the beginning
$('video' +[counter]).load();
// Play the video
$('video' + [counter]).play();

//Increment the counter if there are still more divs to show, otherwise reset it to 0
counter == videos.length-1 ? counter = 0 : counter++;}, videos[counter][1]);
```

on load(), this is the problem in jquery document... Index is empty...

```
jQuery.fn.load = function( url, params, callback ) {
    var selector, type, response,
    self = this,
    off = url.indexOf( " " );
```

Comment: Which index is not defined?

Comment: Line 27... $('#'+ "video" + [counter]).load();

Answer (score 0):

```
var videos = [
["div1", 11000],
["div2", 11000],
["div3", 2000],
]
```

try

```
var videos = [
  {"div1", 11000},
  {"div2", 11000},
  {"div3", 2000},
]
```

also, because they are ids you are referencing, put # in front:

Example - $('#'+videos[counter][0]).show();

Comment: It says line 27...  $('#'+ "video" + [counter]).load();

Comment: Thanks, but changing the brackets did not work. I did add the '#' + but it is still not recognizing the index.